# C# IF/Else Array

Tags: c#, arrays, literate-programming

I am trying to create a simple array example in C# that iterates through the array and only shows values that are greater or equal to 2, but less than 4.

In the if statement I am not sure how best to formulate a two part statement within the iteration function. This is the example I have, which obviously doesnt do anything: else if (array[i] >= 2 array[i] <4)

The full code I am trying to create:

```
int[] array = new int[5];

            array[0] = 1;
            array[1] = 2;
            array[2] = 3;
            array[3] = 4;
            array[4] = 5;

            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                if (array[i] >= 4)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(array[i]);
                }
                else if (array[i] >= 2 array[i] <4)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(array[i]);
                }
                else
                {}

            }
            Console.ReadKey();
```

Looking for suggestions on how best to create this function.

Comment: You have to combine the two results using some logical functions - in this case `AND` which in `C#` is `&&`.

Comment: Your condition should be `if (array[i] >= 2 && array[i] <4)`. Read about [Conditional logical operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691310%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: you can save some code by using a `foreach` instead

Comment: Not sure why, but the many of these answers have neglected your `array[i] >= 4` comparison. Be careful if taking the code directly

Comment: Because while the code shows an >= 4 comparison, the text of the question does not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it in one statement:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    if (array[i] >= 2 && array[i] < 4)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(array[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

LINQ is your friend

```
var selected = array.Where(x => x>= 2 && x < 4);
```

and if you really want a one liner with the console IO

```
array.Where(x => x>= 2 && x < 4).ToList().Foreach(x=>Console.WriteLine(x));
```

Comment: This is the way to do that... Also for beginner `x => x >= 2` may be a bit foreign :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [conditonal AND operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx) (`&&`)

```
else if (array[i] >= 2 && array[i] <4)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers have mentioned, you are missing the conditional AND operator (&&).

Using it would change your

`else if (array[i] >= 2 array[i] <4)`

to

`else if(array[i] >= 2 && array[i] < 4)`

But, you can do one better with your current code. Since you are doing the **same operation** in your `if` and in your `else if`, and you are comparing against `int` with a continuous comparison (ie: 2,3,4 etc return true).  You can further simplify it to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    if(array[i] >= 2)
    {
         Console.WriteLine(array[i]);
    }
}
```